# Paste range of cells to first empty row and empty columnn

Tags: excel, vba

What im trying to achieve is to copy 3 first cells from sheet "Arkusz1" and paste it sheet "Arkusz2" to first empty column and first empty row in that column. After this the process reapeats until first row will be filled with 10 cells then copying proceed in next row. I have code wich paste it to first empty row in column A but it doesnt work properly as described above. I will apreciate any help.

```
Sub y()
LastRowy = Sheets("Arkusz2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastCol = Sheets("Arkusz2").Cells(LastRowy, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set targetRNg = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("A4")


With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz2")
  colCount = Arkusz2.UsedRange.Rows(LastRowy).Columns.Count
End With
MsgBox colCount
If colCount > 10 Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2

Line1:

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz2")
    Set destRng = .Cells(LastRowy, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(targetRNg.Rows.Count, targetRNg.Columns.Count)
    destRng.Value = targetRNg.Value

End With
```

Comment: Are you running this in Excel or is this a VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using statements like - `Goto Line 2`
Instead, read excel and find out how many cells do you need to copy and create a loop to repeat that many times.

Following statement looks incorrect to me:

```
colCount = Arkusz2.UsedRange.Rows(LastRowy).Columns.Count
```

You can use following functions to get to the row that you want and read/set values accordingly

```
Function fn_GetLastColumn(ByVal sSheetName As String, ByVal iRow As Integer) As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
    fn_GetLastColumn = sht.Cells(iRow, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function

Function fn_GetLastRow(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal iColNo As Integer) As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)

    'Ctrl + Shift + End
    fn_GetLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, iColNo).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Comment: Hi could you please explain how to use it in my case?

Comment: Its slightly difficult without knowing what exactly you are trying to do. However, depending on whether the source data (in Arkusz1 is fixed or variable) I will read the data from source into a variable (either directly from hardcoded cells or by finding out the data and then reading it into variables).

Then,

iLastCol = fn_GetLastColumn("Arkusz2", 1) will give me last empty column (assuming a non empty column has data in 1st row.

I'd copy values using ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz2").Cells(1, iLastCol) = varSourceValue1

Comment: Hi thank you. After some time I have  managed to use your functions properly and achieved goal.